# How to choose right name for 2 same classes?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having difficulties for editing this 2 things, i can't find the solution to edit individually in css.

[image]

Can you help me ?

Comment: 1 line questions??!! write details else your question will be removed very soon

Comment: div input[name="first_name"] { } and the other div input[name="email"] { }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to any HTML attribute to select individual elements:

```
input.zu-input-text[name="name"] {
     /* CSS for "Name" text input */
}

input.zu-input-text[name="email"] {
     /* CSS for "E-Mail" text input */
}
```

Theoretically, you could do that with `placeholder` property too.